# Why do Tri-Y Headers give more low end torque and struggle at top and why 4-1 Headers give better top end torque?

Tags: engine-theory, exhaust, exhaust-manifold

Everywhere i read says Tri-Y is better for bottom end and that the 4-1 is better for top end. Why exactly is that? I thought Tri-Y would have more top end "breathing" and make more torque at top since it looks better suited for exhaust pulse scavenging but thats wrong according to the stuff i read and i would like to know the exact reasoning behind it.

Comment: The book by David Vizard Tuning minis has a bit about that and you can build a test table like he did.... But you are getting into turbulent flow and how gases behave which is not easy.

Comment: You state: "... the stuff I read ..." ... I'd be curious to know what that "stuff" is? Could you include some links to what you're talking about so we can all be on the same sheet of music?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦ Sorry yeah i should have included some stuff. here are two of them : https://www.onallcylinders.com/2020/06/29/mailbag-explaining-4-1-vs-tri-y-exhaust-header-collectors/      ,       http://www.superstreetonline.com/how-to/aftermarket-parts/htup-0804-honda-header-tri-y-vs-4-into-1-dyno-test

Comment: I took the dyno data from the second link you provided and worked it backwards for torque thinking I might be able to correlate what is said in the articles. I built a chart of the numbers and displayed them accordingly. I'm not able to come up with a logical reason *why* it is doing what it's doing, though the numbers confirm the theory of tri-y for down low torque (though it does equal stock at that level) and 4:1 for higher HP (which equates to higher torque as well when compared to the other two). The scavenging effect is what gets you more HP/TQ, but why is still the mystery.

Comment: You ate probably looking to be able to combine the effects of laminar & turbulent flow (changing as the flow increases / decreases in each pipe section), pressure drop - think bernoulli and those tube paint sprayers that we blew through as kids or the sound produced by blowing across the top of a bottle and the effects of the valve overlap as well as the acceleration of the flow in each section and inertia effects.